# Comparing the values of maps in GO

Tags: dictionary, go

I have to compare the values (not keys) of two maps of type '`map[string]float64`'.

The contents of the maps are : `map1[ABCD:300 PQRS:400]` and `map2[ABCD:30 PQRS:40]`
No I do a check like if value(map1)/value(map2) > = 1 (like 300/30=10>1), then do something.

How can I achieve this in GO ?
TIA.

i tried something like this :

```
for key := range m2{
            for k := range m1{
                temp := m1[k] / m2[key]
                fmt.Println("temp*******", temp)
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does `value(map1)` mean?  `map1` has two different values, should `value(map1)` be 300 or 400?  Do you know how to access the value of a map for a given key?

Comment: Hi Amit, 

i want to run a loop and compare the values associated amongst each keys. 
So basically what I want to do is : 300/30;400/40 and so on...
Hope you got my query. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Will you know for sure that the two maps have the same keys?  Could it be possible that `map1` has some key that `map2` does not have, or vice versa?

Comment: Nope, they both have same keys and both have exactly same datatype as I have shown. 
Please go through my code as I have just edited in my question.

Comment: The question is still very unclear.  You say something like, "if value(map1)/value(map2) >= 1 ... then do something" but in the code you showed, there is no `if`.  Do you want to "do something" **for each key** where the condition holds?  Or do you only want to "do something" once, if the condition holds **for all keys**?  Maybe you can provide a couple different examples of input, and what the expected output is.  In other words, be explicit about the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

[Playground working example](http://play.golang.org/p/3IfXHig8EB)

Breaking down the main for loop:

```
for key, value1 := range m1 {
    if value2, ok := m2[key]; ok {
        fmt.Printf("%f / %f = %f\n", value1, value2, value1/value2)
        if value2 != 0 && value1/value2 > 1 {
            fmt.Println("Greater than 1!")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Not greater than 1!")
        }
    }
}
```

First I use `range` to pull out both a value and a key for every entry in m1, since we need both.

Second, using the **comma ok** syntax of `value2, ok := m2[key]`, I'm both finding out what the associated value of the second map is for the given key, and also ensuring that that map entry exists when the surrounding `if ... ; ok`. From your description of the problem, it isn't necessary to check every element of the second map, only those that share keys with the first. It's important we make this check, since go doesn't throw errors when checking a map for a non-existent key, it just silently returns the zero-value of the variable--in this scenario that could mean dividing by zero later on.

Third, well, just some formatted printlines to help see what's happening, the real juice is the very simple `if value1/value2 > 1` statement. Note that I also added in my playground link some map entries that don't fulfill the requirement to help demonstrate that the behavior is correct.

The "go maps in action" blog article linked in the other answer is indeed a great source for working with maps in go.

Comment: You don't test for division by zero: `value1/value2 > 1`

Comment: True, easily fixed and done. Interesting that the above code wasn't panicing, but worse: `value1/value2 > 1` was resolving as true when value2 was zero.

Comment: Due to the peculiar behavior of IEEE 754: `zero := float64(0); fmt.Println(42.0 / zero)` is `+Inf`.